# white box in chrome covers page

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm developing a website and today Google chrome has decided to show this big white box.
A week ago i didn't have this problem and i haven't changed the code since.

I don't have the problem in other browsers(ie and firefox).

Actually seems to be a problem with this monitor. I'm extending my laptop display and if i have the browser open on the laptop display there's no problem. But having it open on the monitor i get this big white box.
The only way i can get it to disappear on the monitor is if i zoom to 150%+.

Chrome is updated i even tried uninstalling and re installing.

Just curious has anyone else had this problem?
Any Fixes?

there is the image of what it looks like
http://postimage.org/image/kodmqafb5/

Comment: Are you running any extensions in Chrome? If so, try disabling them and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Probably a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023246/whilte-frame-overlay-in-chrome-for-gwt-app , but we did not find solution yet :(

Answer (score 0):

if you have download keeper enabled in extensions it's the reason for the white box atleast on mine anyways i just got rid of it and then chrome downloaded it again just get ri of it when it happens should fix your problem