# Whilte frame overlay in Chrome for GWT app

Tags: google-chrome, gwt

In the recent versions of Chrome we have started to get a very annoying problem with our GWT-application.

On some page loads we get a big white overlay almost covering the whole application.
Anyone seen this and know what is causing it?

I've tried to inspect with developer tools but the frame doesn't seem be any html-element.
A resize or reload of the window/page resolves the problem.

[image]